# Use a dynamic URL in blade style barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I'm generating a PDF via: [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

I can't seem to get the dynamic URLs to work.

**Example:**

Inside my blade file I have inline style setup like so and I need the background image to be a full path:

```
<style>
.cardbg{
background: url('https://examplesite.com/images/pic.jpg')
}
/* I've tried the following variations with no luck.
I don't understand why this is not working. */
        background: url('{{asset('/images/pic.jpg')}}');
        background: url('{{public_path('/images/pic.jpg')}}');
        background: url('{{storage_path('/images/pic.jpg')}}');
        background: url('{{config('app.url').'/images/pic.jpg'}}');

</style>
```

Also added the direct path to a variable in my Controller like this:

```
    public function examplePdf($id){
        $pdfbg = config('app.url').'/images/pic.jpg';

        $pdf =  PDF::loadView('admin.dir.example-pdf', compact('pdfbg'))->setPaper('letter', 'landscape');
        return $pdf->stream('example.pdf');
```

Then call like this in blade `<style>`:

```
.cardbg{
background: url('{{$pdfbg}}');
}
```

Still nothing... Which doesn't make sense because when I do a `dd($pdfbg);` I get the correct path to the image. `"https://examplesite.com/images/pic.jpg"`

---

I did get the full path to render correctly Outside the `<style>` tags by doing this:

```
<img  src="{{public_path("/storage/images/folder/$var->example/profile-img/$var->img_name")}}">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You Are better off with using the URL facade and calling the asset method for this kind of situations. You have to remove `url()` as `{{assets()}}` is giving you a `url` already

```
{{ URL::asset('public/images/pic.jpg') }}
```

or you can try like that

```
{{ url('/') }}/images/pic.jpg
```

Comment: Man was really hoping that would work, but it did not. Can I not use php inside style tags on a blade template? The only thing that works is hard coding in the URL. `background: url('https://example/images/pic.jpg')`... Which stinks because I have to use `.gitignore` on these files or hard code in the URLs every time I make a commit.

Comment: This has to be related to the barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package. I'll continue to search the issues in there. If I find a working answer I will post.